# How to make a 'Pro' version of an Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, project

I have just made an app and now I'm planning to make a 'pro' version of it, so I want to copy my Xcode project and rename it.

I was just wondering what the easiest way is to go about doing this. Obviously there are a lot of different references to the name throughout the project and I don't really want to spend ages searching through, updating them all.

Please can you suggest the easiest steps to take in order to copy 'App Basic' to 'App Pro'? Or is there a better/preferred method to create a 'pro' version of an app with subtle differences?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a second target in the same Xcode project. You can then define two preprocessor macros (e.g.: `APP_VERSION_LITE` & `APP_VERSION_PRO`) and do compile time switching using `#ifdef APP_VERSION_PRO` etc.

In your app delegate you can define a string with your application name

```
//.pch
extern NSSting * const MyAppName

//appdelegate.m
#ifdef APP_VERSION_PRO
NSSting * const MyAppName = @"App Pro";
#else
NSSting * const MyAppName = @"App Lite";
#endif
```

You can also include files (including resources and classes) only in one of the two targets.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. How do I go about making subtle changes to the code though. For example, in the 'lite' version I have iAds displayed, however in the 'pro' version I don't want to display these.

Comment: Just wrap the version specific code in `#ifdef APP_VERSION_LITE ... #endif` or `#ifdef APP_VERSION_PRO ... #endif` as appropriate, that way the code will be stripped out before compilation as needed. You can have separate PCH files for each target in which to do your definitions.

Answer (score -2):

Well, when i have to release an update of an app, i usually copy the folder and paste it by changing its name.

You could act the same way, without losing any data but "upgrading" it to the "pro" version, by adding things to the app, changing its name etc.

This is the way i do it, i might be wrong (and i'm pretty sure i am lol), but you can try this way!

Comment: I have tried doing this but it doesn't seem to update the app name in all of the file names throughout the project. I basically want to do a search and replace throughout the project where I look for 'App Baisc' and replace it with 'App pro'.

Comment: Oh, i got it. Have you tried to update it through the target's Build Settings? (Target - Build Settings - All - Packaging -> Product Name and Info.plist) [Just to begin] 
You can also try to take a look here: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/18/tutorial-same-xcode-project-create-multiple-products-for-iphone/ and here http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/03/tutorial-part-2-same-xcode-project-create-multiple-products-for-iphone-using-script/ and this answer to understand what to change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235019/how-do-i-duplicate-my-xcode-project-iphone-sdk